# How can an up-to-date copy of a file be stored in a Git repository without changes to it being tracked?

Tags: git

I have a large database file stored in a Git repository. This file is updated and saved to the repository regularly. I do not want Git to keep track of this file now, though I do want the file to be stored in the repository and to be up-to-date; the large size of the file suggests that an approach more appropriate than tracking every single change to it would be to save an occasional "release" copy of the database to the repository.

How should this be done?